# Python open() modes and file writing

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm learning PyGTK and I'm making a Text Editor (That seems to be the hello world of pygtk :]) 
Anyways, I have a "Save" function that writes the TextBuffer to a file. Looks something like

```
try:
    f = open(self.working_file_path, "rw+")
    buff = self._get_buffer()
    f.write(self._get_text())
    #update modified flag
    buff.set_modified(False)
    f.close()

except IOError as e:
    print "File Doesnt Exist so bring up Save As..."
    ......
```

Basically, if the file exist, write the buffer to it, if not bring up the Save As Dialog.

My question is: What is the best way to "update" a file. I seem to only be able to append to the end of a file. I've tried various file modes, but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point where you write to the file, your location is at the end of the file, so you need to seek back to the beginning.  Then, you will overwrite the file, but this may leave old content at the end, so you also need to truncate the file.

Additionally, the mode you're specifying (`'rw+'`) is invalid, and I get IOErrors when I try to do some operations on files opened with it.  I believe that you want mode `'r+'` (*"[Open for reading and writing](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file."*).  `'w+'` is similar, but would create the file if it didn't exist.

So, what you're looking for might be code like this:

```
try:
    f = open(self.working_file_path, "r+")
    buff = self._get_buffer()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(self._get_text())
    #update modified flag
    buff.set_modified(False)
    f.close()

except IOError as e:
    print "File Doesnt Exist so bring up Save As..."
    ......
```

However, you may want to modify this code to correctly catch and handle errors while truncating and writing the file, rather than assuming that all IOErrors in this section are non-existant-file errors from the call to open.

Answer (score 6):

You **can** open a file in `"r+"` mode, which allows you to both read and write to the file, and to seek to particular positions and write there. This probably doesn't help you do what I think you want though; it sounds like you're wanting to only write out the changed data?

Remember that on the disk the file isn't stored as a series of extensible lines, it's just a sequence of bytes; some of those bytes indicate line-endings, but the next line follows on immediately. So if you edit the first line in the file and you write the new first line out, unless the new one happens to be **exactly** the same length as the old one the second line now won't be in the right place, so you'll need to move it (and have taken a copy of it first if the new line you wrote out was longer than the original). And this now means that the next line isn't in the right position either... and so on until you've had to read in and write out the entire rest of the file.

In practice you almost never write only part of an existing file unless you can simply append more data; if you need to "alter" a file you read it in, alter it in memory, and write it back out **or** you read in the file in pieces (often line by line) and then write out to a **new** file as you go (and then possibly move the new file over the top of the original). The first approach is easiest, the second is better for not having to hold the whole thing in memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in as a list, add an element to the start of it, write it all out. Something like this.

```
f = open(self.working_file_path, "r+")
flist = f.readlines()
flist.insert(0, self._get_text())
f.seek(0)
f.writelines(flist)
```

Comment: I think that's because I copied the OP's rw+ rather than r+. Fixed.